# Entity Framework relation between the same classes

Tags: entity-framework, foreign-keys, entity-relationship

I have a `Location` class, and I want that class to have references to another two `Location` objects: PreviousLocation and NextLocation. I have tried this:

```
public class Location
{
    public int LocationId { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("LocationId")]
    public Location PreviousLocation { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("LocationId")]
    public Location NextLocation { get; set; }
}
```

But it gave me an error when running `Add-Migration` command: There are multiple navigations in entity type 'Location' which are pointing to same set of properties - 'LocationId' using ForeignKeyAttribute.

Could anybody show me an example of how to achieve my desired behavior?

Comment: You have given same ForeignKey name to both of PreviousLocation and NextLocation. I think, ForeignKey names should be **PreviousLocationId** and **NextLocationId**

Answer (score 0):

Try this. This will allow Recursive or hierarchical referencing.

```
public class Location
{
    public int LocationId { get; set; }

    public int NextLocationId { get; set; }
    public int PreviousLocationId { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("PreviousLocationId")]
    public Location PreviousLocation { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("NextLocationId")]
    public Location NextLocation { get; set; }
}
```